# Fitting a model to data that starts at x=1

Tags: python, matplotlib, model-fitting

So, I'm trying to fit a two state model to my data. When I run my code I come into the problem that The Xnet line is one trial behind my data points. I need to find a way to make the data points and Xnet line align.

This is the code that actually gets the plot line for the Xnet, Error (E), XS (Slow State), and XF (Fast state):

```py
slow = np.concatenate([SmeanPhase1, SmeanPhase2, SmeanPhase3, SmeanPhase4])
fast = np.concatenate([FmeanPhase1, FmeanPhase2, FmeanPhase3, FmeanPhase4])

# two State model function
def two_state(params, slow, fast):
    As, Bs, Af, Bf = params

    XS = np.zeros_like(slow)
    XF = np.zeros_like(fast)
    Xnet = np.zeros_like(slow)
    E = np.zeros_like(slow)

    for i in range(len(slow) - 1):
        E[i] = fast[i] - Xnet[i]

        XS[i + 1] = As * XS[i] + Bs * E[i]
        XF[i + 1] = Af * XF[i] + Bf * E[i]

        Xnet[i + 1] = XS[i + 1] + XF[i + 1]

    mse = np.mean((slow - XS) ** 2) + np.mean((fast - XF) ** 2)

    return mse

#initial paramaters
As_guess = 0.9
Bs_guess = 0.05
Af_guess = 0.5
Bf_guess = 0.2

# define bounds so graph looks right
As_bounds = (0, 1)
Bs_bounds = (0, 1)
Af_bounds = (0, 1)
Bf_bounds = (0, 1)

bounds = (As_bounds, Bs_bounds, Af_bounds, Bf_bounds)

result_fast = minimize(two_state, (As_guess, Bs_guess, Af_guess, Bf_guess), args=(fast, fast), bounds=bounds)
result_slow = minimize(two_state, (As_guess, Bs_guess, Af_guess, Bf_guess), args=(slow, slow), bounds=bounds)

As_opt, Bs_opt, Af_opt, Bf_opt = result_fast.x
As_opt_slow, Bs_opt_slow, Af_opt_slow, Bf_opt_slow = result_slow.x

XS = np.zeros_like(slow)
XF = np.zeros_like(fast)

E = np.zeros_like(slow)

Xnet = np.zeros_like(slow)

# Get plot points for OPtimized two state model
for i in range(len(slow) - 1):
    E[i] = fast[i] - Xnet[i]

    XS[i + 1] = As_opt_slow * XS[i] + Bs_opt_slow * E[i]
    XF[i + 1] = Af_opt * XF[i] + Bf_opt * E[i]

    Xnet[i + 1] = XS[i + 1] + XF[i + 1]
```

And this is the code that handles plotting the data (on two different figures):

```py
plt.scatter([trial for trial in trials[:len(JP1)]], SmeanPhase1, color='#FD8B0B', label="Slow Group (15s/tick)")
plt.errorbar([trial for trial in trials[:len(JP1)]], SmeanPhase1, yerr=SstdevPhase1, capsize=4, color='#FD8B0B')

plt.scatter([trial + 10 for trial in trials[:len(JP2)]], SmeanPhase2, color='#FD8B0B')
plt.errorbar([trial + 10 for trial in trials[:len(JP2)]], SmeanPhase2, yerr=SstdevPhase2, capsize=4, color='#FD8B0B')

plt.scatter([trial + 20 for trial in trials[:len(JP3)]], SmeanPhase3, color='#FD8B0B')
plt.errorbar([trial + 20 for trial in trials[:len(JP3)]], SmeanPhase3, yerr=SstdevPhase3, capsize=4, color='#FD8B0B')

plt.scatter([trial + 30 for trial in trials[:len(JP4)]], SmeanPhase4, color='#FD8B0B')
plt.errorbar([trial + 30 for trial in trials[:len(JP4)]], SmeanPhase4, yerr=SstdevPhase4, capsize=4, color='#FD8B0B')

plt.scatter([trial for trial in trials[:len(MP1)]], FmeanPhase1, color='#0BB8FD', label="Fast Group (5s/tick)")
plt.errorbar([trial for trial in trials[:len(MP1)]], FmeanPhase1, yerr=FstdevPhase1, capsize=4, color='#0BB8FD')

plt.scatter([trial + 10 for trial in trials[:len(MP2)]], FmeanPhase2, color='#0BB8FD')
plt.errorbar([trial + 10 for trial in trials[:len(MP2)]], FmeanPhase2, yerr=FstdevPhase2, capsize=4, color='#0BB8FD')

plt.scatter([trial + 20 for trial in trials[:len(MP3)]], FmeanPhase3, color='#0BB8FD')
plt.errorbar([trial + 20 for trial in trials[:len(MP3)]], FmeanPhase3, yerr=FstdevPhase3, capsize=4, color='#0BB8FD')

plt.scatter([trial + 30 for trial in trials[:len(MP4)]], FmeanPhase4, color='#0BB8FD')
plt.errorbar([trial + 30 for trial in trials[:len(MP4)]], FmeanPhase4, yerr=FstdevPhase4, capsize=4, color='#0BB8FD')

plt.plot(Xnet * 2, label='Xnet State', color="green")

plt.legend()

#Two State Model plotting
plt.figure()

plt.title("Task Data Two State Model Fitting")
plt.xlabel("Trials")
plt.ylabel("Adaptation Index")

plt.plot(E / 10, label='Error', color='r', linestyle="--")
plt.plot(Xnet / 10, label='Xnet State', color="green")
plt.plot(XS / 10, label="Slow State", color="#FD8B0B")
plt.plot(XF / 10, label="Fast State", color="#0BB8FD")
```

[This is my full code](https://zerobin.org/?06d191a090733e04#DAUD8hnYuTmvcY7yCQFZqZWzwmDsKkgLSSH861rptAx8) if it's needed in anyway to help out.

So far I've haven't tried much but I also don't know what to try.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.